# Disposed exception when trying get objects list via AWS C# SDK (digitalocean)

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, digital-ocean

Why when i try to get objects list (or buckets list for example) i get Disposed Exception?

> System.ObjectDisposedException: "Cannot access a disposed object.
>   ObjectDisposed_ObjectName_Name"

```cs
private string S3_ACCESS_KEY = "blablabla";
private string S3_SECRET_KEY = "blablabla";
private string S3_HOST_ENDPOINT = "https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com";
private string S3_BUCKET_NAME = "launchers";
private AmazonS3Client _client;

public DO()
{
    AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();
    config.ServiceURL = S3_HOST_ENDPOINT;
    _client = new AmazonS3Client(S3_ACCESS_KEY, S3_SECRET_KEY, config);
}

public List<string> ListObject()
{
    var objects = _client.ListObjects(S3_BUCKET_NAME); // System.ObjectDisposedException: "Cannot access a disposed object.ObjectDisposed_ObjectName_Name"
    var objectsList = objects.S3Objects.Select(c => c.Key).ToList();
    return objectsList;
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you getting this exception?

Comment: I added a comment there. The first line of the ListObject function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still did not understand what was the reason, but I solved the problem.

1. Removed awssdk and installed awssdk.s3 (Nuget)
2. Changed the code

```cs
public List<S3Object> ListObject()
{
    var objects = _client.ListObjectsAsync(S3_BUCKET_NAME).Result;
    return objects.S3Objects.ToList();
}
```

Now it works

Comment: I use tests to play around with code that uses services like S3. I don't need to have that run on the build server. It's only to get my code correct.